# Assigning HTML5 geo coordinates to JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm attempting to assign a global variable to HTML5 geolocation coordinates in JavaScript and passing these via jQuery to a form field.

The problem I'm having is assigning the lat and long to a global variable. I know the geolocation api is exposed via "navigator.geolocation" but I must be missing something in assigning these values to the global variable.

Here's my attempt:

```
    var latitude = null;
function lat()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    }
}

var longitude = null;
function lon()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        longitude = position.coords.latitude;
    }
}
```

Any help in ironing out the mistake would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Tried this. Doesn't work in obtaining the value but also doesn't result in a Firebug error:

```
    var latitude = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  lat = position.coords.latitude
  return lat
});

var longitude = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  lon = position.coords.longitude
return lon});
```

Comment: Where is `position` defined? Also: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..edit2: updating with more useful example for callbacks..

```
function requestCurrentPosition(){
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(useGeoData);
        }
}

 function useGeoData(position){
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    /*do stuff with long and lat here.*/
  }
```

..edit: updating example...

```
var latitude = null;
function lat()
{
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position){
              latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        });
}
}

var longitude = null;
function lon()
{
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position){  
            longitude = position.coords.latitude;
        });
    }
}
}
```

You might want to check out this [HTML5 Demo](http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation)

Comment: The map function works fine. Just need to be able to access the lat and long at a global level and am having a challenge assigning a global variable those values.

Comment: This is close. I changed var latitude = null to var latitude = new lat() and the same for longitude. What appeared in the form, though, was [object Object]. It is getting closer, but not quite. Using "null," nothing appears in the form.

Comment: Its a call back function, so your cant just assign it like that. Add a console.log(latitude)  and console.log(longitude) inside the function(position) blocks, the value will be defined, however if you assign latitude =lat() your actually assigning the variable to the function pointer

Comment: getCurrentPosition takes in a callback function and doesnt return anything because the user may have to give permission for the site to use the geolocation information. If you want to work with the position data, you will need to do it within the function(position) call

Comment: A little confused. So how do I get the actual numeric value assigned to the variable? Because "null" returns nothing to the form. JS is a bit confusing. Your insight is very appreciated.

Comment: Basically whats happening is your sending a callback function as a parameter to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() . After the user gives permission and the device determines the location, the call back function is executed with a parameter 'position' which contains the geo data. Instead of using the Global variables to store the position information, could you just work with them inside the callback function?

Comment: Here's the deal. I'm trying to place the latitude and longitude into HTML form fields using jQuery ($("#id_latitude").val(latitude);
$("#id_longitude").val(longitude);. To get the "val" to place in the form ID, I need it to be global. I don't know how to access it otherwise. Is there a better way?

Comment: I've updated my post with a new example. What your going to want to do is place your ($("#id_latitude").val(latitude); $("#id_longitude").val(longitude); code inside the /* do stuff here*/ block. Keep in mind though, if they deny the request for GEO data, that function may never be called. So you could have blank values for your text boxes.

Comment: heres a quick jsfiddle with what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/p4QY9/ If you accept the geo request, your data will pop into the text boxes, but if you deny it, nothing will show up.

Comment: It worked! I never thought of placing that jQuery snippet inside the actual function. Thank you! I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

How about something more like this:

```
// Does this browser support geolocation?
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
}
else{
    showError("Your browser doesn't support geolocation!");
}

// Now get user's location

function locationSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
}
```